# Get contiguous subset from given N numbers using less numbers of loop

Tags: php, algorithm, time-complexity

Here is code :

```
echo "<pre>";
function getContigousSubSet($n) 
{ 

    $set_array =  range(1,$n); 
    $main_array = array();
    for ($i=0; $i <$n; $i++) {  
         for($j = $i;$j < $n; $j++){  
          $interval_array = array();
          for ($k = $i; $k <= $j; $k++){
                array_push($interval_array,$set_array[$k]);
          }  array_push($main_array,$interval_array);
         }

    }
  return $main_array;
}

$result = getContigousSubSet(3);

var_dump($result);
```

Can complexity become O(n) by using any mathematical logic or other ways around?

My expectation is need to convert this code to single for loop so that complexity can be O(n).

If anyone suggestion in Python also I am fine with it. I Just need to see it's possible way to do or not.

There is way to get numbers of possible contiguous subset using mathematical formula.

(n⋅(n+1))/2

for ex A[] = [1,2,3] the sub arrays are: [1],[2],[3],[1,2],[2,3],[1,2,3]

(3⋅(3+1))/2, i.e. 6 non-empty sub arrays

Comment: If you want to get subsets and print them, it can't be O(n). You can't generate them without actually making them.

Comment: can it be without using three for loop ? n will be input. Like we can get count of contiguous subset using formula. same way any other way ?

Comment: There is implementation for such a problem [Maximum_subarray_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) the example in python and its O(n), but in your case you are printing the output to file them that would make it more than O(n)

Comment: printing is just example actually need array of subset. If able to get reduce loop then i can add that code to get subset.

Comment: There are n^2 contiguous subarrays, so it is impossible to ouput all of them faster. Real complexity (output length) is cubic if we consider also subarray sizes, so three for-loops solution is optimal (for the task of all subarrays output)

Comment: what will be solution to make n^2 ?

Comment: N^2 subarrays, but ouput size is N^3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reduce the time complexity as you want to generate all subarrays. However, you can make use of [`range`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function in PHP to reduce the nested loops to 2.  Note that this doesn't technically reduce the nested length to 2, [see range function code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L2732) but the code looks more idiomatic.

```
<?php

function getContigousSubSet($n){ 
    $result = array();
    for($i=1; $i<=$n;$i++){  
        for($j=$i;$j<=$n;++$j){
            $result[] = range($i,$j);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

print_r(getContigousSubSet(10));
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/fZu5V

Answer (score 1):

no there is no way to make this happen.
even for printing this you have to use a loop 3 times.
but there is a recursive way, that can make it faster than this.

second possibility is to take it like Boolean.

0 0 0 0  ->  _ _ _ _  (empty sate)

0 0 0 1 -> _ _ _ A ({A})

....
and so on

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-program-to-generate-power-set/ here you can see the code. i have written the code but lost it. hope you get your solution there

Comment: this is not contiguous subset. ac should not come.

Comment: congarray(arr){
   if (sizeof(arr) ==1){
 print arr;
   }else {
        for 1 to sizeof(arr):
  print(arr[k to sizeof(arr)])
 congarray(arr[1 to sizeof(arr)-1])
 
   }
} this is only logic and  psudocode, it is not a PHP or any other language code